# Unique Topological Sort for DAG with Multiple tsort Solutions

Tags: sorting, graph-algorithm, topological-sort

I have a DAG (directed acyclic graph) which has more than one valid topological sorting. I'm looking for a way to sort it topologically and apply a secondary ordering to always get the same, well defined result.

For example take this graph:

A-->B

A-->C

B-->D

C-->D

There are two solutions to a topological sort:

1: A, B, C, D and

2: A, C, B, D

We notice that B and C can be sorted in any order. Therefore we choose alphabetic sorting as secondary sorting to get only one solution: A, B, C, D.

Can this be generalized to any DAG and how can this be implemented?

Comment: Answer by jcm69 can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2051092/unique-topological-sort-for-dag

Answer (score 0):

So the question you're asking is referring more to programming semantics than to the algorithm itself. The Topological Sort algorithm at its basic level assumes that the user will adjust the algorithm to account for whatever he/she may need the algorithm to do. So in order to get the ABCD solution rather than ACBD one, you would need to assert in your algorithm that in a situation where there are two possible candidates, the character with alphabetic precedence will be selected. In order to generalize this to any DAG, you're really just specifying it in your algorithm.

On the flip side, if you wanted to ensure that the same ordering of nodes won't be selected each time, you could randomize the way that a node is chosen when you have multiple candidates.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the standard topological sort with a tie-breaker function?  I.e., don't use the DFS approach, but rather iteratively (or recursively) remove and enqueue vertices with no remaining restrictions.   Each time more than one unrestricted vertex is available, use the tie-breaker function to select between them.    Your tie breaker function would (as I understand your problem) simply select the vertex whose label appears first alphabetically.